# If M is a mxn matrix, then prove that $(MN)^T=N^TM^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this had something to do with the basis vectors e1, e2, e3 but I'm not sure how to go about it or if that was relevant.

Comment: At what point exactly are you having trouble proving this?

Comment: Ok, I think I just figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** An efficient approach is as follows: begin by showing that $(Nx)^T = x^TN^T$ for any column vector $x$.  It then follows that for the standard basis vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$, we have
$$
e_i^T(MN)^Te_j = [(MN)e_i]^Te_j = [M(Ne_i)]^Te_j = (Ne_i)^TM^Te_j = e_i^T(N^TM^T)e_j
$$
Thus, the matrices $MN$ and $N^TM^T$ have the same entries.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the definition
of matrix product
and transpose.

If $A$ is $i$ by $j$
and $B$ is $j$ by $k$,
then
$(AB)_{u,v}
=\sum_{w=1}^j A_{u,w}B{w,v}
$.

Also,
$A^T_{u,v}
= A_{v,u}
$.

Therefore,
since
$B^TA^T$ is $k$ by $i$
(because
$B^T$ is $k$ by $j$
and
$A^T$ is $j$ by $i$),

$\begin{array}\\
(B^TA^T)_{u,v}
&=\sum_{w=1}^j B^T_{u,w}A^T_{w,v}\\
&=\sum_{w=1}^j B_{w,u}A_{v,w}\\
&=\sum_{w=1}^j A_{v,w}B_{w,u}\\
&\text{and}\\
(AB)^T_{u,v}
&=(AB)_{v,u}\\
&=\sum_{w=1}^j A_{v,w}B{w,v}\\
&=(B^TA^T)_{u,v}\\
\end{array}
$